# How Use Auto Increment value in two columns

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

i have a users complain table in which two columns specifies id of each complain row

```
`complaint_id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`complaint_code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
```

i want if user provide complain_code then it will be inserted normally and complaint_id have its AUTO_INCREMENTED value,
but if user skip to fill complain_code field than it also filled by complain_id's AUTO_INCREMENTED value same as complaint_id.

I can do it with Insert then Update statement but i want to use only
 single insert statement.

i don't know how to do it, please help. i am using mysql, PDO, php

Comment: not a good idea but you can get the max id and make it  + 1

Comment: @knowledge.... unable to use target same as insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too hard if you make use of a MySQL trigger.

The trigger can be set to execute automatically as soon as an INSERT is done  in your table, and it will check if the comaplain_code is blank. If it is blank,  will use the next autoincrement value of complain_id for the comaplain_code as well:

Create a trigger by running this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_complain_code
BEFORE INSERT ON `user_complaints` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    DECLARE next_id INT;
    SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='user_complaints');

    IF NEW.complaint_code is NULL OR NEW.complaint_code = ''
    THEN
        SET NEW.complaint_code=next_id;
    END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```